# Angular ng infinite scroll flickering issue

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I am using a ng infinite scroll in the page to display images. I have a search textfield, which makes the page flicker everytime i type something in search box. How i can disable this flickering effect.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should make a minimal [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) or equivalent, something we can run, see the problem, and perhaps fix it by editing the code